# Single sign on in drupal multi site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I wanted user s registered in one sub site to login to another sub site without re registering , i came accross this module called [single sign on](http://drupal.org/project/sso) but it needs user to be registered in one master site to login to other ubb sites automatically , i need the opposite all sub sites to be treated as master site i.e he can register anywhere and log in anywhere.
i have written one user module which uses core drupal user methods to login/register previously.is there a way to override the sessions used by user module of drupal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to set this up would be to use a single site with domain access rather than a multi site install. It's likely you're past that point, though. So I'd recommend you do the following - write a custom module that alters the user login form on all sites except the single sign on multi site to point to the master site, and set a redirect back to the subsite. For example.

```
function  mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('user_login' == $form_id) {
    $form['#action'] = 'http://masterdomain.com/user/login';
    $form['#redirect'] = url('user', array('absolute' => TRUE));
  }
}
```